# How do I execute the following php array?

Tags: php, jquery, associative-array, script-tag

I need to print the $positions array so I used php for loop..But I also have JQuery function inside for loop so I wrote script tag surrounded by echo statement. But ' and " got messed up. How do I correct it or is there other way?? Also I don't know AJAX.

```
<?php
for ($i=1; $i <=2 ; $i++) { 

echo '<script type="text/javascript">  
$("#position_fields").append(
            '<div id="position'+countPos+'"> \
            <p>Year: <input type="text" name="year'+countPos+'" value="<?php  echo ($positions[ $i ]['year']);?>"  /> \
            <input type="button" value="-" \
                onclick="$(\'#position'+countPos+'\').remove();return false;"></p> \
            <textarea name="desc'+countPos+'" rows="8" cols="80"> <?php echo (htmlentities($positions[ $i ]['description'])); incr($i);  ?> </textarea>\
            </div>');
</script>';
}
?>
```

Comment: There is no array in your code - and messing up quotes is a good indicator that you should start using a proper templating engine

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing PHP and Javascript, and it has some errors.

I replaced countPos with $i and I fixed the code. I didn't run it, try it yourself.

```
<?php

    $positions = array(); /* Your array */

    for ($i=1; $i <=2 ; $i++) { 

        echo '<script type="text/javascript">  
            $("#position_fields").append(
            <div id="position'.$i.'"> 
            <p>Year: <input type="text" name="year'.$i.'" value="'.($positions[ $i ]['year']).'"  />
            <input type="button" value="-" 
                onclick="$(\'#position'.$i.'\').remove();return false;"></p>
            <textarea name="desc'.$i.'" rows="8" cols="80">'.(htmlentities($positions[ $i ]['description'])).'</textarea>
            </div>\');
            </script>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: I tried running it but it's giving out error like:  Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'...

Comment: I tried and I'ts working fine. Make sure that you have an array in $positions.